# Cannot save value in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am encountering a problem in my Android application where my app crashes when I try to save a value.  I am making an online currency converter.  Here is my part of my code:

```
View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            try {
            convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
            float k = Float.parseFloat(convertvalues("USD", "EUR"));
            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Pref", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putFloat("dollarseuros", k);
            editor.commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Pref", 0);
                float val = Float.parseFloat(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
                float k = Float.parseFloat(convertvalues("USD", "EUR"));
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
                String l = df.format(k * val);
                edittexteuros.setText(settings.getString("dollarseuros", l));
            }
        }
```

What my app is supposed to do is to get the value of the USD to EUR rate, then save it until there is no internet connection.  It is supposed to use the cached value when no internet connection is available.

Here is my LogCat:

```
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:240)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is wrong?  I have checked Google and StackOverflow, but nothing solves my problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's on line 240 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: Can you post the `convertvalues(String, String)` method?

Comment: @vikram I have added the convertvalues method.

Comment: Please see my edit below.

Comment: @vikram That doesn't seem to be the problem.  All the other currencies (indian rupee, euro, japanese yen) all work.

Comment: `07-24 00:16:14.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""` - As you can see, the exception is telling you that an `Invalid float: ""` is causing this exception. Look at line 240 of your activity. The problem is on that line.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `NumberFormatException` which means, in Float.parseFloat(stringToParse), `stringToParse` cannot be parsed to a float.

For example, `Float.parseFloat("")` or `Float.parseFloat("Not a float")` will throw a `NumberFormatException` because the empty string `""` or `"Now a float"` cannot be parsed to a float value. Check what you are feeding to Float.parseFloat() and you will overcome this issue.

Edit

Based on `convertvalues()` method you have posted now:

```
public String convertvalues(String convertfrom, String convertto) {
                double current;
                double val = Double.parseDouble(
                                edittextdollars.getText().toString());
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
                 YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();                  
                     try {
                        current = ycc.convert(convertfrom, convertto);
                        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
                        return "";    //           <----------- Problem
                        }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                        return "";    //           <----------- Could be a problem
                    } 
}
```

Your `convertvalues()` method returns an empty string no matter what. You are returning an empty string in both try and catch block. Is this what you really want to return?

Comment: @user2507301 See what `convertvalues();` returns. and why is it called twice?